# Relationships are not displaying properly in Neo4J

Tags: node.js, neo4j, postman

I'm just starting out with Neo4j and I've been trying to send over simple relationships using Postman. I'm not having any issues sending the Nodes but the second I try to create a relationship, it creates two arbitrary grey nodes and builds the relationships. However, when I send a command like this:

```
CREATE (a:Person { name:'Tom Hanks', born:1956 })
-[r:ACTED_IN { roles: ['Forrest']}]->
(m:Movie { title:'Forrest Gump',released:1994 })
```

It properly displays the nodes and the relationship between them. See image below for more clarity.

[image: Sample Graph]

This seems a bit odd as I would assume you'd be able to easily add nodes or create relationships at any point rather than when the Node's are being created.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the query that did not work as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create Relationship after the node is created using Match clause.

For e.g.

```
MATCH (node1:node),(node2:node)
WHERE node1.val=20 AND node2.val=21
CREATE (node1)-[r:Rel]->(node2)
RETURN r
```